# Pasar código en mysql a código mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo un pedazo de codigo en mysql pero me da un error y necesito pasarlo a mysqli, necesito ayuda, gracias

```
       $pegaUser = BD::conn()->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = ?");
                $pegaUser->execute(array($email));

                if ($pegaUser->rowCount() == 0) {
                    echo 'Não encontramos este login!';
                } else {
                    $agora = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                    $limite = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+2 min'));
                    $update = BD::conn()->prepare("UPDATE `usuarios` SET `horario` = ?, `limite` = ? WHERE `email` = ?");
                    if ($update->execute(array($agora, $limite, $email))) {
                        while ($row = $pegaUser->fetchObject()) {
                            $_SESSION['email_logado'] = $email;
                            $_SESSION['id_user'] = $row->id;
                            header("Location: chat.php");
                        }
                    }//
                }
```

Ahora lo tengo así, pero tampoco me funciona

```js
<?php
            if (isset($_POST['acao']) && $_POST['acao'] == 'logar') {
                $email = strip_tags(trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));
                if ($email == '') {
//                    echo 'Email';
                } else {
                    $pegaUser = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE (email ='" . $email . "' OR username= '" . $email . "'");
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($pegaUser);

                    var_dump($pegaUser, $row);

                    if ($row == 0) {
                        echo 'No encontramos ese Logín!';
                    } else {
                        $agora = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                        $limite = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+2 min'));

                        $update = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE user SET connected = ?, limited = ? WHERE email = ?");
                        if ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($update(array($agora, $limite, $email)))) {
                            while ($row = $pegaUser->fetchObject()) {
                                $_SESSION['email_logado'] = $email;
                                $_SESSION['id_user'] = $row->id;
                                header("Location: chat.php");
                            }
                        }//
                    }
                }
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: Juilán eso no parece ser `mysql_` (API obsoleta). Ese código es a todas luces PDO, por los métodos: `execute()` admitiendo arrays dentro, `rowCount(), fetchObject()`... son todos métodos de la clase PDO. ¿Por qué quieres pasarlo a `mysqli`? PDO es tan seguro como `mysqli` e incluso es más flexible si un día tienes que cambiar de mysql a Postgresql, Oracle, SQL Server... Si desde aquí `BD::conn()` devolvieras una instancia PDO el código funcionaría casi seguro, a no ser que haya algún error de sintaxis.

Comment: Yo es que apenas estoy empezando con Mysql y con PHP entonces de cualquiera de las dos formas estoy teniendo problemas el cambio lo solicite por que esta con mysql y ya me da problemas en relación a que esta descontinuado

Comment: Pero si tienes PDO quédate con PDO. Como decía, el código es PDO, pero no sé lo que tienes en la clase `BD`. Si muestras lo que hay en el método `conn` de esa clase entonces podremos saber si hay que responder con PDO o con `mysqli`. Cualquiera de las dos son válidas, pero conviene que te decidas por cual usar.